# iOS Use Vary For Traits Between iPhone Sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, traits

I have a button that I want to be different widths depending on which kind of iPhone is being used.  Obviously a larger width for the 7 Plus, and smaller on down the line.  I click the button, click Vary for Traits, choose Height, change constraints for each iPhone, then click Done Varying and build, but it always keeps whatever the last constraint I edited was, no matter which device I run it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vary For Traits has nothing to do with different iPhone sizes. All iPhones (in portrait) have identical traits; there is nothing to vary.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Really wish they could adjust that to make adjustments...especially since there's more variations of iPhone than iPad.

Comment: Just use auto layout directly. That's what it's for.

Comment: This answer cannot be correct. That would idiotic design. How can you have larger/smaller fonts based on the phone screen size?